# Laravel4 - Auth::attempt() not working - Can't Login (Larabook Tutorial)

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I am following along with the "Build Larabook from Scratch" series on Laracasts
I have checked the code over and over but can't find my error.
I am able to register a user and so Auth::login($user) works, but I cannot get Auth::attempt() to work.

I have tried the following (and much more). I cannot figure it out.

- moving Users back to app/models
- using a simpler User model (standard)
- gone over the videos 3 times trying to identify if I mad ea mistake
- turned filters on and off
- hashing the password and not hashing them before

**How can I debug this problem?! I want to know WHY Auth::attempt() failed!!**

**Please help!**

**My Route for Login**

```
Route::post('login', [
    'as' => 'login_path',
    'uses' => 'SessionsController@store'
]);
```

**My SessionsController constructor() and store() methods [Logging is temporary to try to solve this problem]**

```
public function __construct(SignInForm $signInForm) {

    $this->signInForm = $signInForm;

    $this->beforeFilter('guest', ['except' => 'destroy']);
}
public function store() {
      $input = Input::only('email', 'password');

      Log::info('User tried to login with email => ' . Input::get('email') . ' and password => ' . Input::get('password'));

      $this->signInForm->validate($input);

      $info = [
          'email' => Input::get('email'),
          'password' => Input::get('password')
      ];

      if (Auth::attempt($info)) {
          Log::info('AUTH ATTEMPT was successful');
          // Add flash message "Welcome Back"
          return Redirect::intended('/statuses');
      } else {
          Log::info('AUTH ATTEMPT failed');
          return Redirect::to('login');
      }

    }
```

**My SignInForm.php**

```
namespace Fujibook\Forms;
use Laracasts\Validation\FormValidator;

class SignInForm extends FormValidator {

    /**
     *Validation rules for the registration form
     * @var type 
     */
    protected $rules = [
        'email'     => 'required',
        'password'  => 'required'
    ];
}
```

**My create.blade.php**

```
<h1>Sign In</h1>


{{ Form::open(['route' => 'login_path']) }}

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('email', 'Email:') }}
    {{ Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required']) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:') }}
    {{ Form::password('password', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required']) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">

    {{ Form::submit('Sign In', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
</div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

**Finally, my User Model \Fujibook\Users**

```
<?php

namespace Fujibook\Users;

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

use Fujibook\Registration\Events\UserRegistered;

use Laracasts\Commander\Events\EventGenerator;
use Eloquent, Hash;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait,
        RemindableTrait,
            EventGenerator;

    /**
     * Which fileds that may be massassigned
     * 
     * @var type 
     */
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    /**
     * Passwords must always be used;
     * @param type $password
     */
    public function setPasswordAttribute($password){
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Register a new user
     * @param type $username
     * @param type $email
     * @param type $password
     */
    public static function register($username, $email, $password) {
        $user = new static(
                compact('username', 'email', 'password')
                );

        // raise an event
        $user->raise(new UserRegistered($user));

        return $user;
    }

}
```

**Additionally, I have set the model in the model in app/config/auth.php**

```
'model' => 'Fujibook\Users\User',
```

**And I might as well include my DB migration**

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 70);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->rememberToken();
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you figure out the answer? I have the same problem. I just started the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly you don't need to use `Input::get()` again to get the email and password. What is the field in the database called, username or email? I'd imagine email, if so, change the login code to look like this:

```
public function store() {
  $input = Input::only('email', 'password');

  Log::info('User tried to login with email => ' . Input::get('email') . ' and password => ' . Input::get('password'));

  $this->signInForm->validate($input);

  if (Auth::attempt($input)) {
      Log::info('AUTH ATTEMPT was successful');
      // Add flash message "Welcome Back"
      return Redirect::intended('/statuses');
  } else {
      Log::info('AUTH ATTEMPT failed');
      return Redirect::to('login');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I'm seeing is just this

```
$info = [
      'username' => Input::get('email'),   <--- username = email???
      'password' => Input::get('password')
];

if (Auth::attempt($info)) {
```

Shouldn't it be like:

```
$info = [ 'email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password') ];
```

Comment: Oh, that was another thing I tried. I tried authorizing with the username/password and email/password. Neither one worked.